# Ubuntu won't load

Tags: nvidia

Here is the video of me trying to load my computer:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Gjgh3yyExWJpMGuM6

I've installed Nvidia drivers on my machine and now I can't load it.
I've looked at many similar posts but all the fixes required starting a terminal which I can't do (tried all cttl+alt Fs).

Would like to load my computer and preferably remove Nvidia drivers and return to the previous ones.

Pretty desperate and looking for help

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Disabled.What should I do next?

Comment: Now try to boot.

Comment: Everything is still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: The solution that relates to my problem starts with "open terminal pressing Ctrl +alt+F1". For me this doesn't open a terminal

Comment: You haven't provided your release of Ubuntu, you may need ctrl+alt+f3 or another fn key  (or really the age of software stack reflect by release of Ubuntu; ctrl+alt+f1 is GUI for my system for example so it's f2-f6).